# MongoDB - How can I use mapReduce to count the frequencies of a value in multiple child elements?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a `MongoDB` collection with about a million records that look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53cf413e86763c3f2e6dca36"),
    "test_data" : {
        "status" : "pass",
        "first_case" : [ 
            {
                "index" : "positionA_str",
                "name" : "test_A",
            }, 
            {
                "index" : "positionB_str",
                "name" : "test_B",
            }
        ],
        "second_case" : [ 
            {
                "index" : "positionC_str",
                "name" : "test_C",
            }, 
            {
                "index" : "positionD_str",
                "name" : "test_D",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to be able to count the number of occurrences of `positionA_str`, `positionB_str`, `positionC_str`, and `positionD_str`.

I've done some research and found a simple example [here](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2010/08/mapreduce-with-mongodb-and-python.html) that shows me how to *almost* complete this using `mapReduce`.

The mapping function I am trying to modify is:

```
function wordMap(){

    //find words in the document text
    var word = this.text.match(/\w+/g);
    if (word == null){
        return;

    }
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        emit(word[i], {count: 1});
    }
}
```

So I need to modify the line `var word = this.text.match(/\w+/g);` to count those values belonging to `index`.

However, I am having trouble finding out how to do just this because they occur inside of an array (under `first_case` and again under `second_case`).

For instance, I would like to say something like:

```
var word = this.test_data.first_case[].index.match(/\w+/g);
```

But the `[]` is not allowed. And also, this doesn't include any way of including the `index` of `second_case`.

**Does anyone have any pointers on how to use `mapReduce` to count the occurrences of each value of `index`, regardless of it's child-position in the element structure?**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this structure is fixed? I mean are there `first_case` and `second_case` exist in every document or it is allowed to exist `third_case` etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you think your example has to do with the query you want to run. What you really want to do here is "emit" each of those index values as a "key" and then just let the "reducer" sum up the occurrences:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(

    // mapper
    function () {

      var mkeys = ['first_case','second_case'];
      var test_data = this.test_data;

      mkeys.forEach(function(k) {
        test_data[k].forEach(function(data) {
          emit( data.index, 1 );
        });
      });
   },

   // reducer
   function(key,values) {
       return Array.sum( values );
   },
   { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

That really is the simplest way of approaching this. Just loop each array and emit the "index" field value then "sum up" all the values of 1 you emitted on each key.

MapReduce will handle very large inputs by incrementally calling that reducer until there is only one value left for each key.